# Components inside Drawer no longer work after updating to from "AntDesign" Version="0.12.7" to "AntDesign" Version="0.14.2"

Tags: ant-blazor

hope this is ok to post here.

I have multiple drawers in my web app containing drop-down boxes, calendars and text inputs. Since I updated to 0.14.2, the dropdowns and calendars no longer work. However, the text fields are all ok. The data populates each of these components as expected (they pull data from the DB and make the items appear correctly.) However, when I try to click on a drop-down item, the drop-down menu does not respond to the change, neither does the calendar etc.

I have looked at all of the docs, and I appear to be doing everything correctly, but this problem persists. As a test, I rendered these components within the row, and everything works as expected; it is only once it is inside of a drawer that it stops working. Everything works as expected in "AntDesign" Version="0.12.7".

Any suggestions?

```
<Drawer Closable="true" Width="720" Visible="drawerVisible" Title=@Pagetitle OnClose="_=>Close(Data)">
    <Row Gutter="16">
        <AntDesign.Col Span="24">
            <Text><b>Title</b></Text>
            <Input @bind-Value="Data.Title" Placeholder=" Please enter a Data Title" TValue="string"></Input>
        </AntDesign.Col>
    </Row>
    <br />
    <Row Gutter="16">
        <AntDesign.Col Span="12">
            <Text><b>Engineer</b></Text>
            <Select Placeholder="Select Engineer" PopupContainerMaxHeight="500px" @bind-Value=Data.UploadedBy ValueName="@nameof(DataUser.UserId)" LabelName="@nameof(DataUser.UserName)" DefaultActiveFirstOption Loading=!Users.Any() DataSource=@Users.Where(u => u.Is_Active == true).OrderBy(u => u.UserName) />
        </AntDesign.Col>
        </Row>
 
    <Row>
        <AntDesign.Col Span="12">
            <Text><b>Customer</b></Text>
            <Select Style="width: 240px;" PopupContainerMaxHeight="500px" @bind-Value=@Data.CustomerId ValueName="@nameof(DataCustomer.CustomerId)" LabelName="@nameof(DataCustomer.CustomerName)" Placeholder="Select Customer" DefaultActiveFirstOption Loading=!Customers.Any() DataSource=@Customers />
        </AntDesign.Col>
        <AntDesign.Col Span="12">
            <Text><b>Priority</b></Text>
            <Select Style="width: 240px;" PopupContainerMaxHeight="500px" @bind-Value=@Data.Priority ValueName="@nameof(DataPriority.Priority)" LabelName="@nameof(DataPriority.PriorityName)" Placeholder="Select Prioirity" DefaultActiveFirstOption Loading=!Priorities.Any() DataSource=@Priorities />
        </AntDesign.Col>
    </Row>
    <br />
    <br />
    <Row>
        <AntDesign.Col Span="12">
            <Text><b>Select Date</b></Text>
            <div class="site-calendar-demo-card">
                <DatePicker TValue="DateTime?" Picker="@DatePickerType.Date" @bind-Value=Data.ExpiryUtc />
            </div>
        </AntDesign.Col>
        <AntDesign.Col Span="12">
            <Text><b>Select Item</b></Text>
            <Select Mode="multiple"
                    Placeholder="Please select"
                    @bind-Values="SelectedItems"
                    TItemValue="int"
                    TItem="string"
                    OnSelectedItemsChanged="OnSelectedItemsChangedHandler"
                    Style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 8px;"
                    EnableSearch>
                <SelectOptions>
                    @foreach (var item in Items) {
                        <SelectOption TItemValue="int" TItem="string" Value=@item.ItemId Label=@item.ItemName />
                    }
                </SelectOptions>
            </Select>
        </AntDesign.Col>
    </Row>
    <br />

   
    <AntDesign.Col Span="24">
        <Button Type="default" Style="float: right" @onclick="_=>Close(Data)">Cancel</Button>
        @if (Pagetitle == "New Data Item") {
            <Button Type="primary" Style="float: right" @onclick="_=>OnSubmit(Data)">Submit</Button>
        } else {
            <Button Type="primary" Style="float: right" @onclick="_=>UpdateDataItem(Data)">Update</Button>
        }
    </AntDesign.Col>
</Drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug it seems. Oh well...

https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/issues/3102